# Shared Library Error

Tags: make, shared-library, cmake

I am trying to install the "libh3dapi". When I run the "cmake ." command in the build folder of H3DAPI is runs fine. But when I try to run "make", it runs for sometime and gives the following error at the end.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(boolobject.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symboles: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libh3dapi.so.2.2.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CmakeFiles/H3Dapi.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 debian Precise. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: ln -s /usr/local/lib/libh3dapi.so.2.2.1 /usr/lib/libh3dapi.so.2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Could be misspelling in names?

From your output I see difference in names:

/usr/local/li **b** /li **n** python2.7.a

/usr/local/li **n** /li **b** python2.7.a:

Comment: the error is shown by the to me. There are not the commands that are given by me. when I try to run 'make' command it gives the error given above..

Comment: I understand that, but it could be that it was incorrectly configured before, for example `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lin/`

Comment: i have checked it. i mis-spelled it here. its correct in the configuration